# Pip/Python FastAI installation error with conflict of backend dependencies

Tags: python, installation, pip, fast-ai

When installing FastAI I get a backend conflict error.

```
pip install fastai
```

Returns the following error:

```
ERROR: Some build dependencies for cymem==2.0.2 from https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/8b/dc/0976e04cc46f86e0dd3ee3797ec68057eaafebf31daca9a076dc138b9920/cymem-2.0.2.tar.gz (from fastai) conflict with the backend dependencies: wheel==0.41.2 is incompatible with wheel>=0.32.0,<0.33.0.
```

Answer (score 1):

Fixed the issue through using Python 3.11. For some reason the error was raised on Python 3.10 and 3.12.